# How to find Pairs within the uniswap V3 subgraph

Tags: uniswapv3

I am trying to use the v3 subgraph to locate new pairs that were made and get their age but i cant seem to be able to figure out how to find the pairs. Essentially what i'm trying to do is when i run the graph it shows a list of the 10 most recent pairs on uniswap. Please help, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't use the subgraph but you could just go to the uniswap factory contract address and look at the list of recent transactions